# App Step in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I created a workflow that creates new items in List B based on status change of List A and deletes item in List A. I added these steps in "App Step" in designer workflow and Logging a comment in Workflow history that the item is deleted. Based on my understanding, this Workflow should be triggered only when the status changes to Approved or denied or closed but looks like the workflow is triggered for every modification and logging comment in History that the item is deleted. Any Advice how to avoid it?

Comment: Is your workflow set to start when "an item is changed"? Can you post an image of your workflow to see your logic?